# How to aggregate over two columns with a condition on the secondary one?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Beginner question - not sure how to phrase the question(s) succinctly (hence why I failed to find something similar in the archive?), so let's go with a fictitious example:

1) You own a hotel chain and want to find out how many rooms, in total over all of your hotels, that are occupied by adult males only.

2) The same as above, but for whatever reason you also want to find out the number of rooms occupied by single males and by 2+ males respectively.

You have a table containing, among other things, the following columns:

```
| guest_ID | hotel_name | room_ID | gender |
```

So the [guest_ID] is some ID column with a unique ID for every person staying at the hotel. The [hotel_name] is the name of each branch and should be irrelevant in the query. [room_ID] is the room number in each respective branch but is unique, so room 237 in The Pink Flamingo has a different ID than room 237 in The Stanley, an int or whatever. And let's say [gender] can take on the values 'male', 'female' or 'child'.

I want to make sure I don't accidentally pick up guest rows from 'mixed' rooms in the result.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: your database is designed very baldy. A time intervall/frame for the bookings is missing. imho [Hotel <1:N> Room <1:N> Bookings <1:N> Guest] should be own tables/entities

Comment: We can help you but we need to see some efforts on trying to solve this by your own. You will need a couple of subqueries for this, also adding the create table + insert statements will facilitate people to help you with a solution.

Comment: Sorry, was just asking to see if there was a way of doing such an aggregation. The real query I need to solve is a lot more complex, involving 4-5 tables. It would only make it confusing going into such detail. But in my efforts so far it looks like, if we translate, I do get a room count that includes mixed rooms, and maybe some double counts as well (from joins over non-PK columns). The database structure could be better, I'm sure. Not my design. Not designed for this query. Doesn't help, though, as I'm still expected to get the data. If you don't feel like helping, then don't. It's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how many rooms, in total over all of your hotels, that are occupied by adult males only

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROOMS
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        room_ID
    FROM 
        MyTable
    OUTER APPLY 
    ( 
        SELECT CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_MALE
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY 
        room_ID 
    HAVING 
        SUM(T.IS_MALE)/COUNT(*) = 1
) AS ROOMS
```

> The same as above, but for whatever reason you also want to find out the number of rooms occupied by single males

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROOMS
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        room_ID
    FROM 
        MyTable
    OUTER APPLY 
    ( 
        SELECT CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_MALE
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY 
        room_ID 
    HAVING 
        SUM(T.IS_MALE)/COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(*) = 1
) AS ROOMS
```

> and by 2+ males

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROOMS
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        room_ID
    FROM 
        MyTable
    OUTER APPLY 
    ( 
        SELECT CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IS_MALE
    ) AS T
    GROUP BY 
        room_ID 
    HAVING 
        SUM(T.IS_MALE)/COUNT(*) = 1 AND COUNT(*) >= 2
) AS ROOMS
```

Comment: I'd change `SUM(T.IS_MALE)/COUNT(*) = 1` for `SUM(T.IS_MALE) = COUNT(*)` just because seeing a division makes me worry for 0 division error (even if it can't happen with a group by). Can also replace `SUM(T.IS_MALE)` for `SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 END)` and avoid the APPLY.

Comment: Thanks April Rain! (And EzLo for the comment.) Super easy for the SQL savvy, I'm sure, but really helpful to me. And elegant(!) I asked around elsewhere and we discussed some solutions involving e.g. temp tables with counters, and/or a new relational table to deal with the structural mess. Would probably work but not anywhere near as stylish.